# Use a global variable in my SqlDataSource tag

Tags: sqldatasource

Any suggestions how I can substitute a variable into my database connection string with a global variable in a SqlDataSource tag?

Like: *<%$ ConnectionStrings:Production %>*" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Production.ProviderName %>">

To this: *<% Globals.s_dbConnectionString %>*" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Production.ProviderName %>">

Comment: I don't see any difference

Comment: My code sample is truncated...but it is the ConnectionString I'm referring to. Currently it points to the Web.config, I'd like to change it to a global variable.